# POST jQuery method working but not returning JSON response

Tags: jquery, http-post, flask-restful

I'm trying to save JSON response as a variable from my POST request. The front-end script sends POST to API which then passes it to Trello to create a new board. The board is successfully created and I get the JSON response in from Trello to API. When I try to pass the very same response to the front-end it does not seem to work. I don't know much about javascript and front-end in general so I think I'm doing something wrong with the jQuery here but I'm not sure.

Here's the jQuery request:

```
function submit(boardname){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: `/trello/${boardname}`,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      console.log('Success', data)
      $('#response').html(data)
  }
});
}

$("#submit").click(function(){
  let name = document.getElementById("board-name-input").value
  submit(name)
});
```

And here is my API post function to trello (using Flask-restful):

```
class TrelloBoard(Resource):
    @check_token
    # create public board with default list
    def post(self, name):
        try:
            url = f'https://api.trello.com/1/boards/'
            query = {
                'key':'mykey',
                'token':'mytoken',
                'name':f'{name}',
                'defaultLists':'true',
                'prefs_permissionLevel':'public'
            }
            response = requests.post(url, params=query)
            print(f'Response: {response.json()}')
            return response.json() 
        except:
            return {"message": "Unexpected error ocurred."}, 500
```

Edit, this is the response on the server:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2020 00:02:10] "GET /trello HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Response: {'id': '5fd1658238fc9278a577c913', 'name': 'test', 'desc': '', 'descData': None, 'closed': False, 'idOrganization': '5fcbfac3eb5f7a81b67c3570', 'idEnterprise': None, 'pinned': False, 'url': 'https://trello.com/b/bPvx3oGp/test', 'shortUrl': 
'https://trello.com/b/bPvx3oGp', 'prefs': {'permissionLevel': 'public', 'hideVotes': False, 'voting': 'disabled', 'comments': 'members', 'invitations': 'members', 'selfJoin': True, 'cardCovers': True, 'isTemplate': False, 'cardAging': 'regular', 'calendarFeedEnabled': False, 'background': 'blue', 'backgroundImage': None, 'backgroundImageScaled': None, 'backgroundTile': False, 'backgroundBrightness': 'dark', 'backgroundColor': '#0079BF', 'backgroundBottomColor': '#0079BF', 'backgroundTopColor': '#0079BF', 'canBePublic': True, 'canBeEnterprise': True, 'canBeOrg': True, 'canBePrivate': True, 'canInvite': True}, 'labelNames': {'green': '', 'yellow': '', 'orange': '', 'red': '', 'purple': '', 'blue': '', 'sky': '', 'lime': '', 'pink': '', 'black': ''}, 'limits': {}}
```

I would like to save this data in a variable so I can display a link to the board when it's created [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNY3b.png)

Comment: Can you also share your HTML? And maybe an example JSON response? I don't understand what you want to happen vs what is currently happening

Comment: @assembly_wizard At the moment, the 'success' function doesn't return anything. I've added more details to the post.

Comment: But is the JSON response logged to the browser console? If so, then the result is in the `data` variable, so you can have an `<a>link</a>` element inside of your response element, and change where it links to on success `$('#response a').attr('href', data.url)`

Comment: Nothing is logged to the console, console.log('Success', data) is meant to print the response as in examples I found on google, but in my case nothing happens